# Flutter SaveArea enable the bottom bar dont works?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

Hy Flutters,

I have a Problem with SaveArea Widget, I would enable the bottom bar, but it cann't work for me.

here is my code i writed:

```
return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        bottom: false,
        child: Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
          overflow: Overflow.visible,
          children: [
            NavigationBar(),
            AppBody()
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

[image: This is a image of my app]

what should i do to get it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` on the scaffold to `false`